# Media Query for Samsung galaxy s3 and s4

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I am trying to use media query to display text box with different styles for iPhone5,iPhone6,Samsung galaxy SIII and Samsung galaxy S4. For iPhone 5 and IPhone 6 I am getting desirable result. Now when I switch from iPhone to Samsung s3 I am getting correct output but when I try to switch to S4 from S3 I am getting wrong output. Here's the style that I am using for media query. Attaching the screenshots also. I am not getting the actual problem here.

```
    <style>
@media only screen and (device-width:375px){
     .homeDOB{
         width:60% !important;
        height:80px !important;
        background-color: yellow;
} }

@media only screen and (device-width:320px) {
     .homeDOB{
         width:60% !important;
        height:80px !important;
        background-color: black;
} }



@media only screen and (device-width:360px) and (device-height:640px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){
.homeDOB{
width:60% !important;
        height:80px !important;
        background-color: gray;
}
}

@media only screen and (device-width:360px) and (device-height:640px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:3){
.homeDOB{
width:60% !important;
        height:80px !important;
        background-color: red;
}
}



</style>
```

Comment: Can you show the correct and incorrect results?

Comment: I wanted to attach screenshots but I don't have much credit points to add images. Actually correct output should have display width of 60% of the screen, but when I switch from s3 to s4 or s4 to s3 both height and width gets increased, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Galaxy S4, device width it hits at is a little over 400px. Try changing your media query to:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .homeDOB {
        width:60% !important;
        height:80px !important;
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

and see if it work on your mobile phone. Also, this is the viewport must use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

device width for samsung galexy s3 and s4 is 640px.
Try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px){
    //your CSS rules
}
```

Here you can find list of device width/height http://www.canbike.org/CSSpixels/