# Separate Media Query for Samsung S4 and S5

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a Samsung S4 and S5 phone. I am trying to get the correct media query to target both phone.

The code I have is:

```
/*General*/
.divStyle
{
  height:20px;
}

/*Samsung S4*/
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
  //example
  color: yellow
}

/*Samsung S5*/
@media screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
  //example
  color: blue
}
```

I have a css call `divStyle` that aims to target both S5 and S4. However, on S4, the alignment appears differently from S5. So I tried to use media query to target them separately.

When I run the `media query`, both S5 and S4 are showing up as `blue`. But if I comment away the `Samsung S5 code`, both S5 and S4 show up as `yellow`. How do I get the correct media query to register for each of them separately?

Comment: If you are trying to target devices by their specific screen dimensions, then why are you using the min and max versions?

Comment: `min-device-*` has been deprecated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Query for Samsung galaxy s3 and s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382605/media-query-for-samsung-galaxy-s3-and-s4)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that it is not appearing identical on both phone because of the `font size` (settings>display>font size). The S4 font size was larger which made the alignment different.